# What is the natural word to express it is so noisy that you feel your ears are about to explode?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Your children are making so much noise to a level that you feel your ears are about to explode.

It seems English has an adjective "**[ear splitting](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ear-splitting)**" which means "**very loud**".

But I am not sure that phrase is idiomatic.

Is it natural to say "**Knock it off. You are splitting my ear**" in everyday conversations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [deafening](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/deafening) would be the most natural word to use here. You could say

> Knock it off. You are *deafening* me.

Comment: some people suggest using "**you are killing my ears**", but I am not sure which one, "**deafen me**" and "**kill my ears**", is more idiomatic?

Comment: @Tom I've never actually heard the phrase "you are killing my ears" before. Perhaps you're thinking of "you're killing me", but that has a different meaning, which doesn't really have anything to do with the volume.

Comment: so, it could be that the person who suggest "you are killing my ears" might not be a native speaker?

Comment: @Tom That would be my guess. It's also possible that they're using some slang that is well known in their context, but which I'm simply unaware of.

Answer (score 3):

> You’re going to make my ears bleed!

Or, more severely,

> You’re making my ears bleed!

This is used to describe things that are too loud or horrible to listen to, if not both.

(Usually metaphoric.)

Example in use:

- [Memes that make your ears bleed [1] *too loud memes*](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=LYuvhS6FhIg)

Note: *Ear-splitting* is only used as an adjective, not a verb.

Answer (score 1):

#### No, "ear-splitting" applies to the noise, not what it's doing to you.

No, you wouldnt' say "you're splitting my ears". "Ear splitting" is a phrase used to describe sounds, not to say what those sounds are doing; you can't split it up and remain idiomatic. If your shrieking children are hurting your ears, you might say something like "Knock it off; your ear-splitting shrieks are hurting my ears!"